# no flash supported alternative clickable image

Tags: html, image, flash, clickable, alternate

It's been a little while since I have coded so I'm probably missing something pretty simple.  I have also tried other suggestions/techniques provided by previous similar questions on here but none seem to work properly.

PROBLEM:
I have a div with a flash player inside. I have a 'flash not supported' image which is to display if Flash is not installed. This image is to be clickable and once clicked will direct to another page within the site.

What I can't get is the flash player to hide the 'flash not supported' image on devices with Flash installed.

I have tried putting the image in another div or within the object tag or css but it either sits above or below the flash player on sites with Flash. The flash player does not hide it as expected.

I have also tried using iframe instead of the object tags.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

EDIT:  Am trying to do this with out adding swfobject, jquery, js etc etc if poss.

```
<div>
<object width='350' height='85'>
<a href="/anotherpage.html">
   <img src="images/no_flash_alt_image.jpg"></a>

    <all usual flash param stuff here>


 <embed src='http://myflasplayer.swf'>
  </embed>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a div to hold flash and have a background image:
https://goo.gl/NocXfQ
I hope this helps
Please notify me if the code does not work, I did not have time to test it :-)

Comment: that works just fine. Cheers. I may be back with some more bits in the near future. Just getting back into the swin of things!

Comment: if you need any help just ask me :-)

Comment: Great. Cheers @Daniel